# How to filter by date from a ArrayList for a RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, loops, android-studio, for-loop

I have a list of transaction history from an API, which I display in a RecyclerView. But I want to loop through all the date and group items with the same date together and display only one of the dates on in the recyclerview.

JSON Response

```
{
    "_id": "5ebxxxxx8af9xxxxxxxxxxcf9",
    "user": "5ebxxxxx8af9xxxxxxxxxxcf9",
    "transactionType": "earn",
    "transactionAmount": 100,
    "refId": "cvry65nyj7u7a",
    "createdAt": "2020-05-19T08:34:42.528Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-19T08:34:42.528Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5ebxxxxx8af9xxxxxxxxxxcf9",
    "user": "5ebxxxxx8af9xxxxxxxxxxcf9",
    "transactionType": "earn",
    "transactionAmount": 100,
    "refId": "bghyj5t4efm7",
    "createdAt": "2020-05-19T08:34:42.528Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-19T08:34:42.528Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5ebxxxxx8af9xxxxxxxxxxcf9",
    "user": "5ebxxxxx8af9xxxxxxxxxxcf9",
    "transactionType": "earn",
    "transactionAmount": 100,
    "refId": "3kin7cHdcdvbfxhcxr3dM",
    "createdAt": "2020-05-17T08:34:42.528Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-17T08:34:42.528Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5ebxxxxx8af9xxxxxxxxxxcf9",
    "user": "5ebxxxxx8af9xxxxxxxxxxcf9",
    "transactionType": "earn",
    "transactionAmount": 100,
    "refId": "3kin7cHxjbdfuhcxr3dM",
    "createdAt": "2020-05-17T08:34:42.528Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-17T08:34:42.528Z",
    "__v": 0
},
```

Here is the loop I tried using but it doesn't work

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= txnList.size(); i++) {
        String dateCart = txnList.get(i).getCreatedAt();
        holder.txnDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        for (int j = 0; j <= i ; j++) {
            if (dateCart.equalsIgnoreCase(txnList.get(j).getCreatedAt())) {
                holder.txnDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the UI to be display like below

```
Same date| txn type
           txn amount
         | txn type
           txn amount
         | txn type
           txn amount
Same data | txn type
           txn amount
         | txn type
           txn amount
```

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

First sort your list, Add Sorting list code in your activity or fragment class

```
    Collections.sort(txnList, new Comparator<TxnBeen>() {
        public int compare(TxnBeen o1, TxnBeen o2) {
            if (o1.getCreatedAt() == null || o2.getCreatedAt() == null)
                return 0;
            return o1.getCreatedAt().compareTo(o2.getCreatedAt());
        }
    });
```

then set this sorted list to your adapter.

In Adapter class under `onBindViewHolder` function check same created at date:

```
    if (position == 0) {
        String ts1 = txnList.get(position).getCreatedAt();
        String ts2 = "";
        boolean sameDate = ts1.equalsIgnoreCase(ts2);
        if(sameDate){
            holder.txnDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            holder.txnDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txnDate.setText(ts1);

        }
    }else{
        String ts1 = txnList.get(position).getCreatedAt();
        String ts2 = txnList.get(position-1).getCreatedAt();;
        boolean sameDate = ts1.equalsIgnoreCase(ts2);
        if(sameDate){
            holder.txnDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            holder.txnDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txnDate.setText(ts1);
        }
    }
```